# Erro de cadastro em laço de if

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, post, if

Eu tenho um formulário de cadastro:

```
    <form action="Cadastro.php" method="post"> 
         Nome de Usuário: <br> 
         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" algo parecido com o seu nome" size="30px" name="nomeUser"><br>
         Email:<br>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" meunome@example.com" size="30px" name="email"><br>
         Senha: <br>    
         <input class="form-control" id="senha" type="password" placeholder=" min. 8 caracteres" size="30px" name="senha"><br>
         Confirmação de Senha: <br>
         <input class="form-control" id="senhaconfirm" type="password" placeholder=" confirme sua senha" size="30px" onblur="comparar()">
         <br><input class="btn btn-embossed btn-info" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
         <input class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary" type="reset" value="Esquecer">
</form>
```

e o meu cadastro.php tem duas consultas ao banco, um `SELECT`(consulta se existe outra pessoa com o mesmo nome de usuário) e outro `INSERT` (que cadastra), esse insert está dentro de um if junto com a criação de uma pasta, a pasta é criada corretamente, **mas o usuário não é cadastrado no banco**:

```
    <?php
    $nomeUser = $_POST["nomeUser"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];

    //Conectando ao banco de dados
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "authenticationteste");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }


    //Consultando banco de dados
    $authentic = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE nomeUser='".$nomeUser."'");
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($authentic);
    if($numrow > 0){
        echo "<script>
            var confirma = confirm('Erro: O nome de usuário que você requisitou já exite. Tente outro!');
            if(confirma){location.href='index.php#cadastro';}else{location.href='index.php';}
            </script>";
    }else{
        echo "$nomeUser";
        $res = $mysqli->query("insert into login(nomeUser,email,senha,nomeFolder)values('". $nomeUser . "','".$email."','".$senha."');");
        //mkdir ("C:/Users/e/Documents/Uploads/$nomeUser", 0700 );
    }

?>
```

Anteriormente sem o código de SELECT que procurava outros cadastros, ele estava funcionando corretamente. Não sei se o problema está em ter duas consultas ou se está no laço de if, Mas sei que o post está funcionando corretamente e a conexão também. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente está faltando o valor da coluna **nomeFolder** no seu insert.

Deveria estar dessa forma:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("insert into login(nomeUser, email, senha, nomeFolder) values('". $nomeUser . "', '".$email."', '".$senha."', 'C:/Users/e/Documents/Uploads/".$nomeUser."');");
```

Recomendo também que de preferência para o uso do PDO, como está recebendo dados diretamente do form também é recomendado o uso de prepared statement para uma maior segurança.

Comment: Poxa, cara, era isso mesmo, obrigada. Já tentei usar o PDO, mas não consegui implementar ele na parte de login e acabei deixando pra lá. Mas obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Sem problemas cara, ainda assim recomendo que estude PDO, assim que pegar o jeito não vai querer usar as outras opções. De qualquer forma use o [prepared statetment do mysqli](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php), ele tambem possui essa opção.